# Pronunciation of the letter g in Vietnamese

Tags: phonology, vietnamese

According to Wikipedia, the letter `g` represents the voiced velar fricative /ɣ/ in Vietnamese. However, I could swear that, while I do hear people pronounce it as /ɣ/ sometimes, but more often than not, they seem to pronounce it very similarly or identically to the letter `g` in English (voiced velar plosive). That said, I'm unable to find any confirmation for this anywhere online. This makes me think that perhaps, it's just my ears that hear it wrong. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: You could try Forvo.com. Are these people in Vietnam or are they second+ generation speakers?